# Cronjob can not execute smartctl?

Tags: ubuntu, raid, bash, scripting

I have a cronjob installed (Ubuntu 16) that runs with the root user. So in

`sudo crontab -e`

I have the following entry:

`10 5 * * mon /home/userA/raidchecker.sh`

And the script `raidchecker.sh` does this:

```
#!/bin/sh
mail=`which mail`
rec="myemail@gmail.com anotheremail@gmail.com"
now=$( date +%Y%m%d-%H%M-%S )
mdstat=$( cat /proc/mdstat )
details=$( /sbin/mdadm --detail /dev/md2 )
diskusg=$( df -kh )
disk1=$( smartctl -A /dev/sda | grep Realloc | grep Sector )
disk2=$( smartctl -A /dev/sdb | grep Realloc | grep Sector )
disk1f=$( smartctl -A /dev/sda )
disk2f=$( smartctl -A /dev/sdb )
buddyinfo=$( cat /proc/buddyinfo | grep Normal )

echo "Check from $now\n\n=================\nMemory Fragmentation:\n$buddyinfo\n\nAll partitions:\n\n$mdstat\n\n=================\nData Partition:\n\n$details\n\n=================\nDisk Usage:\n$diskusg\n\n=================\nSMARTCTL:\n\nData Disk /dev/sda and sdb:\n$disk1\n$disk2\n\nFull Reports:\nDisk1:\n$disk1f\n\nDisk2:\n$disk2f" | $mail -s "Check from $now" $rec
```

When I execute the script manually from the shell `./raidchecker.sh` the email contains all infos as expected.

When the cronjob executes the script, the parameters disk1, disk2, disk1f and disk2f are empty (do not contain any data).

Why?

Comment: Did you run the script manually with the same user as in the crontab?

Comment: i don't know. I run the script as root. the crontab has been setup by using the same user.

Comment: sorry my bad ... Try appending `2>&1` to the cronjob https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4883069/debugging-crontab-jobs

Comment: @HenrikPingel: did that, no more info in the email. In the syslog I see this : `CRON[9476]: (root) CMD (/home/userA/raidchecker.sh 2>&1)`

Comment: I think i found it out. cronjob can not find the command `smartctl`

Comment: Thank you @HenrikPingel, I added `2>&1` not only to the cronjob but also to those command lines where smartctl is used, so I now found out that cronjob (running as root) could not find the command `smartctl`, i now inserted the full path and it is working! THANKS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to use `/usr/sbin/smartctl` instead of `smartctl` in the script, only this way the cronjob could execute this command.

Answer (score 1):

Using a crontab, most of the usual environment set for a regular user login is absent or reduced (unless you set it), when the script is run automatically by `cron`.

To be sure, it's better to either provide a relevant `PATH`, or give the absolute path to all commands.

Always test a crontab (setting a time a couple minutes after the current time).

- If you want to receive (by email) the standard and also error output, only add  `2>&1` to the command in the crontab
- If you do *not* want to receive any of the output of the crontab command (by email), add  `> /dev/null 2>&1`